# Как перевести двоичную систему в шестнадцатеричную счисления без базовых функций?

Tags: php

Привет Всем! Вот такая у меня задача перевести с двоичной СЧ в шестнадцатеричную.  Вот нашёл функцию стандартную convert_basic(), но к сожалению стандартную функцию в задаче использовать нельзя. Кто поможет, буду очень признательный

Comment: вам просто надо прочитать как это делается, например тут http://math.semestr.ru/inf/16.php и тут http://vestikinc.narod.ru/AB/bin_oct_hex_tr.htm и применить эту практически

Comment: Ну мне потом этот код надо залить в Codeval, а он просит без базовой функции.

Comment: ну так и не делайте с базовой функцией. выше описано как переводить из одной системы в другую. надо просто применить

Comment: Вот в этом и проблема что я понимаю как переводить а как это правильно записать на php не знаю(( Вы хоть подскажите с чего начинать, так как я в этом деле новичок

Comment: ну там же всё написано.....например значение 01010101010111101  переводите в строку....разделяете по 4 штуки.......в старшую добавляем нули (если количество символов не делится на 4 без остатка)....... ..также у вас будет отдельно массив в которой идет соответствие значения в 16-тиричной системе значению в двоичной....как в таблице http://math.semestr.ru/inf/16.php ....... дальше пробегаетесь по разделенным четверкам значений и сравниваете со значением в массиве, когда совпадает записываете........четверки значений могут быть либо в отдельном массиве, либо просто строкой... как удобнее

Comment: А можете скинуть какой то пример, чтоб мне нагляднее будет понятнее

Comment: пример массива? пример цикла по массиву? пример цикла по строке по каждые 4 символа? или пример всего кода?

Comment: Ну если не сложно , то всего кода или цикла по строке на каждые 4 символа. Спасибо огромное.

Comment: цикл по строке `$string = '0110110011000011'; for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i += 4) {
 echo substr($string, $i, 4).'<br/>';
}`

Comment: А можно эту задачу через Foreach решить?

Comment: когда по массиву с заданными значениями будете бежать - можно и его использовать....для строки for в данном случае..........а чем for не нравится?

Comment: Просто в задании я подключаю файл , а там массив с данными $arr = file($argv[1]);

Comment: давай плюсуй люто, решил твою задачу!)

Comment: причем тут файл с массивами данных и цикл по строке?

Answer (score -3):

Переводить следует циклом. Ваш вопрос немного неправильно сформулирован: вы имели ввиду СПЕЦИАЛЬНЫЕ функции, а не БАЗОВЫЕ. Если это так, то мой ответ должен быть Вам полезен. Я сначала перевёл с 2 в 10, потом с 10 в 16. Так удобнее. Вот моё решение:

```
function dotode($x){
    $a=str_split($x);
    $b=0;
    $c=sizeof($a)-1;
    foreach($a as $key=>$val){
        $b=$b+pow(2,$c)*$val;
        $c--;
    }
    return $b;
}
function detohex($x){
    $c="";
    do{
        $a=$x%16;
        $x=($x-$a)/16;
        if($a<10){
            $c=$a.$c;
        }else{
            switch($a){
            case 10:
                $a="A";
                break;
            case 11:
                $a="B";
                break;
            case 12:
                $a="C";
                break;
            case 13:
                $a="D";
                break;
            case 14:
                $a="E";
                break;
            case 15:
                $a="F";
                break;
        }
        $c=$a.$c;
        }
    }while($x>0);

    return $c;
}
print_r(detohex(dotode(1010)));
```

или вот единая функция:

```
function dotohex($x){
    $a=str_split($x);
    $b=0;
    $c=sizeof($a)-1;
    foreach($a as $key=>$val){
        $b=$b+pow(2,$c)*$val;
        $c--;
    }
    $x=$b;
    $a=0;
    $b=0;
    $c="";
    do{
        $a=$x%16;
        $x=($x-$a)/16;
        if($a<10){
            $c=$a.$c;
        }else{
            switch($a){
                case 10:
                    $a="A";
                    break;
                case 11:
                    $a="B";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    $a="C";
                    break;
                case 13:
                    $a="D";
                    break;
                case 14:
                    $a="E";
                    break;
                case 15:
                    $a="F";
                    break;
            }
            $c=$a.$c;
        }
    }while($x>0);
    return $c;
}
```

Comment: А нельзя сразу с 2 в 16?

Comment: @Eugene можно. надо просто эти функции объединить.

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: @Eugene намного проще, чем избавиться от минусов

Comment: Спасибо)Буду теперь во всем этом разбираться, но на моем уровне это очень сложно)))

Comment: @Eugene вы лучше бы на работоспособность проверили бы в начале. Но решение ужасное и нерабочее

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а что там не работает?

Comment: @EgorRandomize если в первом варианте вводить `001010` числом (т.к. вы приводите пример вбивая именно число, а не строку), то выведет **18** (что явно не 16-тиричная система). Если всё же строкой, т.к. видно использование `str_split` в функции, то выведет **A**, а должно выводить **0A**. В принципе, во второй тоже самое.